# Caesar cipher decoder in Java - unexpected output

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to write a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) decoder in Java, but I get unexpected output (see below example).

The `BetterDecrypt()` method takes a string `cipherText` to be decoded, as well as an integer `shiftKey` that is the number of places up or down the alphabet each character of the string is to be shifted. If a character is not in `String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, then I want to keep the character as is, eg "ab4c" should be decoded "bc4d".

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleDecoder {
    public static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public static String BetterDecrypt(String cipherText, int shiftKey) {
        cipherText = cipherText.toLowerCase();
        String message = "";
        for (int ii = 0; ii < cipherText.length(); ii++) {
            char character = cipherText.charAt(ii);
            if (ALPHABET.contains(Character.toString(character))) {
                int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(cipherText.charAt(ii));
                int keyVal = (charPosition - shiftKey) % 26;
                if (keyVal < 0) {
                    keyVal = ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
                char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
                message += replaceVal;
                }
            } else {
                message += character;
            }
        }
        return message;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(BetterDecrypt("ab4c", -1));
        // OUTPUT: 4   EXPECTED OUTPUT: bc4d
        System.out.println(BetterDecrypt("ab4c", 1));
        // OUTPUT: z4  EXPECTED OUTPUT: za4b
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `keyVal < 0` condition is wrapping too much code:

```
                if (keyVal < 0) {
                    keyVal = ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
                char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
                message += replaceVal;
                }
```

It should be

```
                if (keyVal < 0) {
                    keyVal = ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
                }
                char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
                message += replaceVal;
```

Otherwise, you'll omit all shifted characters that *don't* wrap around from a -> z.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything if `keyVal` is greater than 0. Here's the easiest possible fix

```
if(keyVal < 0) {
    keyVal = ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
    char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
    message += replaceVal;
}
else
    message += ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
```